# How to fetch data from stored procedure which is returning table of content

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have a stored procedure which is returning task list with its details. Same procedure I want to use in other place as there also I have similar requirement with some small change.

But is different is I only want to fetch one column value (not all) with aggregate function for eg. to get ***sum(time_left)*** from same procedure.

And as that procedure is global one so I can't change it for a specific requirement on the other hand I don't also want to re-write the same code again.

Below is the way my procedure and its output look like:

**Procedure**

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS PROC_Emp_task$$

CREATE PROCEDURE PROC_Emp_task(IN IN_assigned_to_id BIGINT)
BEGIN  
    SELECT
        Emp_task.task_id,
        Emp_task.name,
        Emp_userstory_task.userstory_id,
        Emp_task.estimated_end_date,
        (Emp_task.alloted_hour- Emp_task.actual_hour) AS time_left,
        APV_Priority.name AS priority,
        Emp_phase_lookup.title AS lifecyce_phase,
        APV_Status.name AS status_name,
        Emp_task.estimated_start_date
    FROM
        Emp_task
    INNER JOIN Emp_userstory_task ON (Emp_task.task_id = Emp_userstory_task.task_id)
    INNER JOIN ApplicationParamValue AS APV_Priority ON (Emp_task.priority_id=APV_Priority.appParamValueId)
    INNER JOIN Emp_lifecycle_phase ON (Emp_task.lifecycle_phase_id = Emp_lifecycle_phase.lifecycle_phase_id)
    INNER JOIN Emp_phase_lookup ON (Emp_phase_lookup.phase_id = Emp_lifecycle_phase.phase_id)
    INNER JOIN ApplicationParamValue AS APV_Status ON (Emp_task.status_id=APV_Status.appParamValueId)
    WHERE
        Emp_task.assigned_to_id=IN_assigned_to_id
    AND Emp_task.status_id <> (SELECT appParamValueId FROM ApplicationParamValue WHERE ApplicationParamValue.name='Completed' 
    AND appParamGroupId=(SELECT appParamGroupId FROM  ApplicationParamGroup WHERE ApplicationParamGroup.groupName='progress_status'))
    AND Emp_task.isActive=1
    ORDER BY estimated_end_date ASC,time_left ASC,priority ASC;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

**Output**
[image]

**I am thinking to apply some simple solution rather then** something like below:

```
SELECT SUM(time_left) FROM (CALL PROC_Emp_task(101));
```

But as we can't call a procedure in a select query. So it didn't worked.

**So how can we reuse the same procedure to get it ?**

Comment: Did you consider accepting another parameter that can say which query to execute?

Comment: Sorry but I can't. As I can't change signature of procedure as it is global one and implemented n-places. Also in actual the procedure have complex implementation (it have so many sub query, joins, dynamic filter criteria).

Comment: could you make the parameter negative as an indicator of which query to run? i.e. 1001 runs the current query -1001 runs your new query? Use the absolute value as the id?

Comment: Yes, I think we can do. I will try to implement. But further if any other solution will be possible then it will be more useful for me

Comment: What is stopping you from writing an another new procedure with the new requirement and calling it?

Comment: No I can't. It will create maintenance issue